# Finite number of consecutive prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Suppose we have $n$ consecutive prime numbers $p_k$ with $n \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_k-p_{k-1}=m$ and $k=2..n$. Is it possible to find $m$ and $n$ in order to have a finite number of these consecutive primes? For example, if we put $m=6,n=3$, for the first $23$ primes, we get only the triplet $(47,53,59)$ satisfying this condition. Obviously, for example, for $n=3,m=2$ (twin primes), there are only three consecutive primes $(3,5,7)$. Is this the only case we can have a finite number of consecutive primes with $n\gt 2$? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $m=2$ for the twin primes?  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are asking.  Pick some prime $p$ not dividing $m$ and work $\pmod p$.  That gives you a bound for the chain.

Comment: There is another trio below 100.  Then there is 251,257,263,269

Comment: Are you sure you want the n primes to be consecutive?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen:Yes. $n$ consecutive prime numbers.

Comment: I doubt this is finite. 

**Theorem (Shiu, 2000):** Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime. $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,q \in \mathbb{N}, q \ge 3$ having $\gcd(a,q)=1$ there exist ‘strings’ of congruent primes $p_{n+1},p_{n+2},\cdots,p_{n+k}$ such that $$p_{n+1} \equiv p_{n+2} \equiv \cdots \equiv p_{n+k} \equiv a \pmod{q}.$$


**References:**

D. K. L. Shiu, Strings of Congruent Primes, Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 61, Issue 2, April 2000, Pages 359–373, https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024610799007863

Comment: For a fixed difference, the number of consecutive primes is finite. But I am not sure whether I actually understand what is exactly asked here.

Comment: The Green Tao theorem guarantees arbitary long arithmetic progressions consisting of only prime numbers, but this theorem is not proven for consecutive primes.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, I can't sort out what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu: I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Well, as I pointed out in my first comment, if $p$ is the least prime not dividing $m$, a chain of length $p$ must contain an element divisible by $p$, hence there are only finitely many such.

Comment: [Consecutive Primes in Arithmetic Progression](http://primerecords.dk/cpap.htm) (CPAP). Some records and information there. The longest known has $10$ consecutive primes. It notes that: "A CPAP-11 would have minimal difference 11# = 2310. This seems extremely hard to find and nobody has even tried as far as I know. With current methods it may take trillions of cpu GHz years according to the people who found the first known CPAP-10."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RATHER LONG COMMENT

For consecutive primes larger than $5$ in an arithmetic progression, the common increment must be a multiple of $6$, as those primes have a form $6t\pm 1$. Any five consecutive positive integers of the form $6t-1$ or $6t+1$ (or $6st \pm 1$ where $5 \not \mid s$) will have one member that is divisible by $5$, limiting sequences of primes to at most $4$ in length.

You can address this by making $5$ a factor of the increment, looking for strings among integers of the form $30t \pm r$ where $r \in \{1,7,11,13\}$, but then strings of $7$ such numbers will contain at least one member divisible by $7$. You could move to numbers of the form $210t \pm r$, but you will appreciate that as the increment of the arithmetic sequence gets larger, the likelihood of finding strings of consecutive primes diminishes.

This does not prove or even suggest that indefinitely long strings of consecutive prime numbers in an arithmetic sequence cannot be found, only that one very quickly is forced to look among very large numbers to have any chance of finding them.